# A question involving a Borel probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure.

Show that for $x \in X,\; \delta > 0$ there exists $ \delta' \in (0, \delta)$ such that $\mu (\partial B(x, \delta')) = 0$.

Every book gives the following answer:

$\underset{\delta' \in (0, \delta)}{\cup} \partial B(x, \delta')$ is an uncountable disjoint union with finite measure.

Can someone explain me why is this the answer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an $\epsilon>0$ such that there are infinitely many $0< \delta' < \delta$ with $\mu (\partial B(x, \delta')) \ge \epsilon$. Taking a countable subset  $I$ of these $\delta'$ you have $\sum_{\delta' \in I} \mu(\partial B(x, \delta'))=\mu (\cup_{\delta' \in I} \partial B(x, \delta')) \le 1$, contradiction since the sum diverges to $\infty$.

To prove the existence of such an $\epsilon$, suppose that for each positive integer $n$, there are just finitely many $\delta'$ with $\mu (\partial B(x, \delta')) \ge \frac{1}{n}$. Then the set of $\delta'$ such that $\mu (\partial B(x, \delta')) > 0$ is countable, contradiction.